# Checkbox and radiobuttons. values

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, radio-button

I have this already, but don't know how to get further.
When I select the checkbox above the 2 radiobuttons, it should see if it is checked, then when I check 1 radiobutton, it should check that one and add the value to the total value.

```
     <form name="CalorieForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="gf"> Groente en fruit <br />
      &nbsp <input type="radio" name="gf1" value="60"> Appel (60 kcal per appel) <br />
      &nbsp <input type="radio" name="gf2"value="26"> Paprika (26 kcal per paprika) <br />
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bpp"> Brood, pasta en peelvruchten <br />
      &nbsp <input type="radio" name="bpp1" value="111"> Zilvervliesrijst (111 kcal per 100 gram) <br />
      &nbsp <input type="radio" name="bpp2" value="24"> Sperziebonen(24 kcal per 100 gram)<br />
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="zvvev"> Zuivel, vlees, vis, ei en vleesvervangers <br />
      &nbsp <input type="radio" name="zvvev1" value="118"> Kabeljauwfilet (118 kcal per 100 gram) <br />
      &nbsp <input type="radio" name="zvvev2" value="115"> Biefstuk (115 kcal per 100 gram) <br />
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vo"> Vetten en olie <br />
      &nbsp <input type="radio" name="vo1" value="108"> Olie (108 kcal per eetlepel) <br />
      &nbsp <input type="radio" name="vo2" value="90"> Halvarine (90 kcal per 25 gram) <br />
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="v"> Vocht <br />
      &nbsp <input type="radio" name="v1" value="0"> Thee (0 kcal per 0.5 liter) <br />
      &nbsp <input type="radio" name="v2" value="0.6"> Coca cola light (0.6 kcal per blikje) <br />
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Bereken de calorieën" name="totaal" onClick="BerekeningCalorie()"> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    <br>
    <br>
    Aantal calorieën: <input type="text" name="Calorie" size="20"><br />
 </form>
```

This is my form ^
And here my unfinished javascript V

```
        function berekeningCalorie() {
var totaal = 0
if document.getElementByName("gf").checked {
 if document.getElementByName("gf1").checked 
  totaal += totaal + document.CalorieForm.gf1.value
 if document.getElementByName("gf2").checked 
  totaal += totaal + document.CalorieForm.gf2.value
 }

if document.getElementByName("bpp").checked {
 if document.getElementByName("bpp1").checked 
  totaal += totaal + document.CalorieForm.bpp1.value
 if document.getElementByName("bpp2").checked 
  totaal += totaal + document.CalorieForm.bpp2.value
 }
}
```

I asked my teacher how to do it, and she said it should be like this (this is what I remembered from what she showed me)

Could somebody fix this up for me? I am not sure how to continue it. (javascript noob).

Comment: `totaal += totaal + document.CalorieForm.bpp2.value` should be: either  `totaal += document.CalorieForm.bpp2.value` or `totaal = totaal + document.CalorieForm.bpp2.value`

Answer (score 0):

There are some pretty fundamental things wrong with your code here.

1. **[HTML]** - I assume you want your radio buttons to work together in their sets. For instance: only select `gf1` or `gf2` (right now you can select both). You do that by their names, so both would have to be `gf1`
2. **[HTML]** - Your buttons `onclick` is capitalized, but your JS is not (`BerekeningCalorie()` vs `berekeningCalorie`
3. **[JavaScript]** - Syntacticly, you need parentheses around all your `if` conditions.
4. **[JavaScript]** - `getElementByName` is not a method. `getElementByNames` (plural) is, but returns an elements collection. You could give them all `id` attributes and use `getElementById`, or just use the `document.formName.inputName` (as you've done for the values `document.CalorieForm.gf1` for instance)
5. **[JavaScript]** - Your calculation should either be `total = total + addition` or `total += addition`; *Your current (`total += total + addition`) is doubling the total, then adding the additional number.*
6. **[JavaScript]** - The input value is actually a string, not a number. So you need to use `parseInt` to add it numerically:
7. **[JavaScript]** - You're not outputting the value, I assume that's what the `[name="Calorie"]` input is for.
8. **[JavaScript]** - Also, for good measure, I assume you realize you're not calculat

You can see the fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/4sHQg/

HTML:

```
<form name="CalorieForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="gf"> Groente en fruit <br />
  <input type="radio" name="gf1" value="60"> Appel (60 kcal per appel) <br />
  <input type="radio" name="gf1" value="26"> Paprika (26 kcal per paprika) <br />
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="bpp"> Brood, pasta en peelvruchten <br />
  <input type="radio" name="bpp1" value="111"> Zilvervliesrijst (111 kcal per 100 gram) <br />
  <input type="radio" name="bpp1" value="24"> Sperziebonen(24 kcal per 100 gram)<br />
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Bereken de calorieën" name="totaal" onClick="BerekeningCalorie()"> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
  <br><br>
  Aantal calorieën: <input type="text" name="Calorie" size="20">
 </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function BerekeningCalorie() {
  var totaal = 0;

  // If our gf checkbox is checked, then get the value of the radio buttons.
  // Each have the name 'gf1' so it doesn't matter which is checked.
  // In case neither is checked, we default to 0.
  // Then we use parseInt to calulate the number and add it to totaal
  // otherwise, we would be concatenating two strings, not adding two numbers
  if(document.CalorieForm.gf.checked)
    totaal += parseInt(document.CalorieForm.gf1.value || 0, 10);

  // Do the same for the next, etc.
  if(document.CalorieForm.bpp.checked)
    totaal += parseInt(document.CalorieForm.bpp1.value || 0, 10);

  document.CalorieForm.Calorie.value = totaal;
}
```

Comment: Oh, it should be like total = total + addition. I used your example, but still not working..

Comment: @user3470213 You're right, there was a lot more wrong with your code. I've updated my answer. Remember to accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I think we're close to what I want. It works now, but there should be only one radio button selectable of the 2. Both should have a value (gf1 has 60 and gf2 has 26).

Comment: also, when the checkbox is not checked, then the selected radiobutton under the checkbox should not give any values to the total. so when checkbox is checked and gf1 then it is total + 60. and if gf2 is checked, then total + 26. if checkbox is not checked, then total + 0. Also, this should be for all 5 checkboxes. so when i select GF1 + bpp1, then it should get total + 60 + 111

Comment: Yup, that's all how my code works. Did you check the jsfiddle link?

Comment: Yes, I used that one, but it says 0 all the time.

Comment: I edited your jsfiddle a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/4sHQg/2/ But it "appel" has a value of 60 and "paprika" should have 26 as value. so when I select "paprika" it should use total + 24 and not total + 60

Comment: @user3470213 Yup. I'm not sure what you're asking, everytie I use it and check a box and check a radio button, it all comes out just fine. I've answered all your questions and taught you the syntatical errors of your original and provided a fully working example on jsfiddle. There's not much more I can do.

Comment: What I actually want is very close to what you got me. I have 2 radio buttons and both should have a different value. so gf1 got 60 and gf2 got 26. What should happen is when I check the checkbox and gf1 it should give me as answer 60 (total + 60). but if I check gf2 instead of gf1, it should give me as answer 26 (total + 26).

Comment: That's exactly what happens in the fiddle I've provided. The trick is there is no gf1 or gf2, they are both gf2. Again, it all works in my example, there's not much more I can do.

Comment: But how is it possible to make 2 values for 2 radio buttons when only 1 can be checked??